# dpkg permission denied error

Tags: apt, package-management, permissions, dpkg

I want to install packages for offline ubuntu16.04. I zipped all the .deb file in **/var/cache/apt/archives** in another machine which can access the internet.  When I use **dpkg -i libboost-all-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb** to install the package, I got permission denied eorror.

```
dpkg:error processing archive libboost-all-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb(--install):
cannot access archive: Permission denied
```

I have used **chmod -R 777 ./**  to change the authority. It doesn't work.

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root Aug 13 16:58 libboost-all-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced this same issue, and the fix was to make the current directory executable to all:

```
chmod a+x .
```

Comment: Which directory did you mean by "current directory"?